# Using 'if' syntax in cypher to execute diferrent queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there any way to write one query for next task.

```
I have (a:A)-[r:RELATES]->(b:B)
and if r.value = 1  with a
Match (c:C{id:a.id}) with c, a
Merge (c)-[q:RELATED_TO]->(a)
ON CREATE SET q.value = 1
and if r.value = 0
// I don't create relationship between c and a but if it exists i set q.value = 0
Match (c)-[q:RELATED_TO]->(a)
Set q.value = 0
```

I tried to use for it FOREACH query for this task

```
Match (a:A)-[r:RELATES]->(b:B) with a, r, b
Match (c:C{id:a.id}) with a, r, b, c
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN r.value = 1 THEN [1] ELSE [] END | 
    Merge (c)-[q:RELATED_TO]->(a)
    ON CREATE SET q.value = 1
)
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN NOT r.value = 1 THEN [1] ELSE [] END | 
    Match (c)-[q:RELATED_TO]->(a)
    ON CREATE SET q.value = 0
)
```

But i get Invalid use of MATCH inside FOREACH. It appears that it might be done with two queries, but i'd like to find out if it's possible with one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems logically equivalent to what you want to do:

```
MATCH (a:A)-[r:RELATES]->(b:B), (c:C {id:a.id})
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[q:RELATED_TO]->(a)
WHERE r.value = 0
SET q.value = 0
WITH c, a, r
WHERE r.value = 1
MERGE (c)-[q:RELATED_TO]->(a)
ON CREATE SET q.value = 1;
```

- If `r.value` is `0` and the `q` relationship already exists, then set `q.value` to `0`.
- If `r.value` is `1`, then create the `q` relationship if necessary; and, if `q` did not previously exist, then set `q.value` to `1`.

Comment: I've met examples with case, but it used in return statement to return different data, but i didn't meet any examples using case for executing different queries. For example MATCH n
RETURN
CASE n.eyes
WHEN 'blue'
THEN 1
WHEN 'brown'
THEN 2
ELSE 3 END AS result

Comment: Yes, it's nice alternative for this task